# Note - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) appearing in mysql error.log

Tags: mysql, debian, webmin

**Note - this was DIFFERENT than other questions found here related to mysql root password reset and connection problems - I had my root password. Something was pinging mySQL at a regular interval trying to use "root" which was odd to me.

I recently had upgraded from 5.1 to 5.7. and had migrated all MyIsam tables so i was tweaking config and I was finding entries in the /var/log/mysql/error.log file that appeared at regular 5 min. intervals ever since enabling log_level=2 in mysqld.cnf. This was spurred by the "aborted connects" variable shown in the phpmyadmin "status=>all status variables" tab numbering in the 1000's.

To my best recollection I did not have monitoring setup for mySQL on this box (debian 8 on GCE) and no scripts use "root" to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching it ends up being the Webmin "System and Server Status" module - I was playing around with this months ago. The fix is either to turn it off OR be sure that your install of webmin has the mySQL root password by going to the left side menu - Servers=>mySQL Database server and adding the pass.

I turned this off as it didn't seem to work well anyway and it seems odd that it would milk the entry made under mySQL vs having its own user.

Hope this helps someone doing a similar search.